# Shopify show collection description on conditions

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to display a description of "Test" collection's page.

If the url is `mysite.com/collections/test` then it will show the description part.

But if the url have extra tags, example: `mysite.com/collections/test/big` it won't show the description.

I tried with this code below but it didn't work:

```
{% if collection.description != blank %}
    {% if collection.url == '/collections/test' %}
    <div class="collection-description regular-content mb30">
      {{ collection.description }}
    </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
```

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an extra condition to the first `if`, which will check if you have added any tags.

```
{% if collection.description != blank and current_tags == blank %}
    <div class="collection-description regular-content mb30">
        {{ collection.description }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

The `current_tags` object lists all tags used in product/articles filtering.

More info here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/current-tags